# i can't enable wireless windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, wireless-networking

I can't enable wireless on my Windows 7 Lenovo N200, How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Is your wireless card turned on. Usually there are keyboard shortcuts that turn it off.

Comment: i cant.. i think my pc was have virus>> but now i cleaned..  how can me fix it ?

Comment: does it have a hardware switch? front-left/left-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wireless radio switch is likely turned off. See number 11 in this diagram which shows where to locate it:

[image]

[Image Source](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=migr-67660).

Comment: OMG!... I AM NOT SEE NUM(11) thank u :)